# How do you calculate the difference in Dates from 2 fields on 2 different rows in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a query that I am trying to find the date difference in columns in 2 different rows. `StartTime` and `EndTime` are in different tables as well. Below is an example of my results and query. I need to find the difference in `EndTime` from row 1 and `StartTime` in row 2. I need to continue this sequence all the way through my results.

```
StartTime               EndTime
2015-04-22 07:53:00.000 2015-04-22 08:27:00.000
2015-04-22 09:12:00.000 2015-04-22 10:46:00.000
2015-04-22 12:12:00.000 2015-04-22 13:06:00.000
2015-04-23 07:36:00.000 2015-04-23 08:34:00.000
2015-04-23 09:50:00.000 2015-04-23 10:48:00.000
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT OP1.Op1DateTime as StartTime,
       OP2.Op7DateTime as EndTime
FROM SchOrPatCases pc
    inner join SchPatOrCaseTimesOp1 OP1 on OP1.CaseID = pc.PatientCaseID
    inner join SchPatOrCaseTimesOp2 OP2 on OP2.CaseID = OP1.CaseID
    inner join AbstractData a on a.AccountNumber = pc.AdmExtUrn
where pc.OperationRoomID in ('ORMAIN03')
and a.PatientClass not in  ('IN','INMCR','INMCD')
order by StartTime
```

Comment: What database provider: MS SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, other?

Comment: use the LAG function to get to the previous row, then just subtract the values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT CAST(OP2.Op7DateTime - OP1.Op1DateTime AS TIME) AS DIFF_TIME
    FROM SchOrPatCases pc
    INNER JOIN SchPatOrCaseTimesOp1 OP1 on OP1.CaseID = pc.PatientCaseID
    INNER JOIN SchPatOrCaseTimesOp2 OP2 on OP2.CaseID = OP1.CaseID
    INNER JOIN AbstractData a on a.AccountNumber = pc.AdmExtUrn
    WHERE pc.OperationRoomID in ('ORMAIN03')
          and a.PatientClass not in  ('IN','INMCR','INMCD')
    ORDER BY StartTime
```

Comment: I didn't realize you could subtract datetime objects in that case I'm not sure what OP's problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Stick them into a CTE

```
;with CTE as
(SELECT OP1.Op1DateTime as StartTime,
       OP2.Op7DateTime as EndTime
FROM SchOrPatCases pc
    inner join SchPatOrCaseTimesOp1 OP1 on OP1.CaseID = pc.PatientCaseID
    inner join SchPatOrCaseTimesOp2 OP2 on OP2.CaseID = OP1.CaseID
    inner join AbstractData a on a.AccountNumber = pc.AdmExtUrn
where pc.OperationRoomID in ('ORMAIN03')
and a.PatientClass not in  ('IN','INMCR','INMCD')
order by StartTime)
select DATEDIFF(dd, Endtime, Starttime)
from CTE
```

This will treat the fields as if they were in the same table.
You can then use the DATEDIFF or equivalent to get the difference in time.

Comment: When I use this code I am getting the DATEDIFF of EndTime from row 1 and StartTime from row 1. I need the DIFF of EndTime of row 1 and StartTime of row 2.